# IIS does not list a website that matches the launch url

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7, windows-vista

I need to debug the website i 'm developing (ASP.NET MVC3, Razor, .NET 4, VS2010 SP1 
(as administrator)) in IIS7 (Vista Home) and getting the error:

IIS does not list a website that matches the launch url.

To test if it has to do something with the settings of the app, i did create from scratch an empty new ASP.NET MVC3 website, set for IIS, created virtual directory, launched with F5 and i worked fine!

I again did create a second website project with the exact same settings (just to be sure) and this also launched as expected.

This leads my to think that i have some configuration problem!? But what? In the past i used IIS very rare, so my knowledge is somehow limited in this direction.

Any hints?

Answer (score 356, accepted):

I hate answering my questions: in my question i stated that i was running VS under the administrator account. **This was not true**!!!

So the solution (for me) was to run VS2010 as administrator (Start->In Vista menu right click-> Run as administrator)...so simple.

As a side effect: VS2010 let me also create Virtual Directories without any problems (prior to that i got error messages stating that i have to manually adjust these)

Comment: Run as administrator gets me every single time!

Comment: #@$%ing `Run as Administrator` has probably cost us developers about 400,000 years in lost development time over the last 6 or 7 years

Comment: Just to add, had the same thing happen with me on Visual Studio 2012. Run As Administrator fixed it also.

Comment: This works for me also, but why exactly do we need to run Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: As a tip, set the VS shortcut to run as administrator so you don't have to right-click, run as... all the time.

Comment: still the case in VS2013

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error in VS 2013. Running VS as administrator resolves the issue, but it's not a solution. I should be able to run VS regular way and still debug.

Comment: FWIW: The [VSCommands plugin](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/) has a setting "Always start VS with elevated permissions".

Comment: still the case in VS2015

Comment: There's no good reason this should still be an issue in 2015.

Comment: Worth noting: Even if you start VS.NET in Administrator Mode, if you leave your machine up overnight and Windows decides to silently install updates and reboot you, you'll come back to an identical looking VS.NET that's *not* running as Admin anymore.

Comment: Still the case in VS15 (which is **not** VS2015, because Microsoft is skilled at giving names like penguins are at flight).

Comment: still the case in VS2017

Comment: still the case in VS 2019

Answer (score 61):

You can set Visual Studio to run always as admin. `Right click on the shortcut => properties => Advanced => tick on run as administrator.`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but not worked for me, Please refer to my answer.

Comment: This setting is a complete булшит, never works and totally meaningless. Why they put that checkbox when it never works is a mystery to me.

Comment: This actually worked for me on my taskbar icon in windows 10, but only when clicking on the icon directly. Right-clicking the icon and selecting a solution to open did not open visual studio in Administrator mode though sadly. I had to use [QMaster's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32278434/1568891) to get that to work.

Comment: For Windows 10, navigate to the devenv.exe, right-click and choose "Troubleshoot Compatability". On the next one, choose Troubleshoot Program, then convince it to do admin by checking the box "The program requires additional permissions".  That's how you get it to stick for all the shortcuts - including your pinned solutions.

Comment: This ticked me off too. Running as administrator made it work again, i.e. I could debug my application running under IIS in Visual Studio again.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and set administrator privilege for shortcut as @karim said not worked for me, so i get to the devnev.exe file and set administrator privilege in compatibility tab and that's worked. I didn't want to add this as an answer but I couldn't assign a picture, so decided to post it as a new answer.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't have a Compatibility tab, try following [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12859334/1028230).

Answer (score 11):

For the benefit of searchers, I was running as admin and still got this, so needed to follow [this blog](http://mvolo.com/fix-problems-with-visual-studio-f5-debugging-of-aspnet-applications-on-iis7-vista/) (obviously ignoring some of the stuff related to old .NET versions).

Following that, did a rebuild and it worked.

EDIT: (Following the comments)

Section 2 was of particular interest. It states:

In order to enable F5 debugging, you will need at minimum the following components:

- ASP.NET
- Windows Authentication Module (Provides support for Windows authentication with NTLM and Kerberous)
- Metabase compatibility layer (Provides support for legacy IIS configuration APIs used by existing software to manage IIS.  Note that this is required to connect to your ASP.NET application from Visual Studio, even before you attempt debugging.)

Install them from Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features on and off:

EDIT: (added paths to features):

- Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security -> Windows Authentication
- Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatability -> IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatability

Comment: If that link dies, will your answer still be useful?

Comment: Apologies - I thought it would be better to reference the original source than try to pass it off as my own knowledge. If SO has guidance showing what I have done is incorrect, please let me know and I will update.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." @ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a new machine - running as admin did not help. The solution was to  execute `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` first. It has to be run from a command prompt that has also been started as an Administrator. Commonly the exe can be found in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` - if you need to change it, you most likely already know what to change.

To always run the program as administrator without the right click, open the VS shortcut properties compatibility tab and check "Run this program as an adminsitrator". For detailed steps, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx

Comment: @monstro it appears that your issue is caused by something other than the issues that my answer or any of the others that are included in "these" addresses.

Comment: This doesn't work on machines I believe Windows 8+.  This only works on Win7- machines.  You have to register new IIS frameworks by either downloading from MSDN or by adding it via Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off >  .NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services > ASP.NET 4.6.  At that point then you should have no problems running as Admin. (My machine = Win X)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start >> Control Panel >> Click Programs
2. Click Turn Windows features on or off.
3. In the User Account Control dialog box, click Continue
4. Expand Internet Information Services, expand Web Management Tools, and then expand IIS 6 Management Compatibility
5. Click to select the IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility check box, and then click OK.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me, I updated VS 2017 version to Version 15.4.2, run with administrator, deleted document folder files(Visual Studio 2017) and restart the pc.