# Add Multiple Folders / Directories to a ZipFile

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am writing a backup program that requires predefined multiple folder(s) & single file(s) to be added to a single zip archive. I have had no issues adding a single folder using -`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(string, string, c..level, bool(false))`
However i am having a hard time adding multiple folders as there does not seem to be a way to update an archive or target two folders using the `CreateFromDirectory` method.
- Would be nice if there was an `UpdateFromDirectory` mehod!

I have been trying to stay away from third party libraries for no reason really, however as far as i have found none deal with multiple unrecursive folders.

I have tried just about everything other than writing my own code to recurse & add individually which i don't really want to do.

The program has several inputs that defines the folders / files to be zipped and depending on whether they are not `null` should add them to a single zip file regardless of whether they are a folder or file.

I guess my question is whether this is possible at all using the boxed libraries without custom recursing or even with a third party library without heavy mods... Not sure if i have made my question clear, sure you will all let me know if i have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell using the ZipFile class you can only create and read. if you want to update you would need to create the whole zip again. [Source: [ZipFile methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile_methods.aspx)]

to target more than one folder you could arrange all the files and folders into one folder then zip the entire source without including the source folder. In most cases moving this files/folders isn't possible so I'd recommend looking into Symlinks within windows. I'd redirect to you [[Issue with creating symbolic link to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504964/issue-with-creating-symbolic-link-to-directory])

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx

Comment: Moving / Copying is def out of the question but a good suggestion with the Symlinks... Will look into it tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can create a "myFolder" folder and put in it all the folders you want found in the zipped folder. Then do **ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("myFolder", "name of zip file to create", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false, Encoding.UTF8)**. Overriding this IncludeBaseDirectory method to false allows this to be done.