# subdomains on local development server (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain

First of all, I have managed this before on another machine using VS 2012 and Windows 8. The only difference I can see with this machine is that I am using VS 2013.

So, I have set up my host file to have this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost:3892

127.0.0.1   r3plica.localhost
127.0.0.1   r3plica.localhost:3892
```

On my working machine the **localhost:3892** doesn't exist and it works without it.
In visual studio everything is set as default. When I f5 the browser goes to **localhost:3892** and everything works as expected.

On my other machine, if I change the URL to **r3plica.localhost:3892** the expected website loads and I can still debug it (debugging is what I need to do).

On my new machine if I change to the new URL I get a **Bad Request** error.

I have searched the internet and can not find the solution, so if anyone has had the same issue, please help me fix it! :D

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: Have had the exact same problem. Worked in VS2012 on Windows 8. Upgraded to VS2013, made no other changes, and now I get the Bad Request error when I go to mysubdomain.localhost:55079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by:

- Running [Visual Studio in admin mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)
- Forcing IIS Express to run in admin mode too (locate `iisexpress.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`, right click and select `Properties` then `Compatibility` tab then tick the 'Run this program as an administrator' checkbox).
- Modifying the `applicationhost.config` file for IISExpress for the site you're debugging. The file can be found at Documents > IISExpress > config. Find the relevant site node and change the bindingInformation attribute to the below (but putting your port number in):

  ```
  <site name="MyWebsite.UI" id="52">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\Code\Latest\MyWebsite.UI" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55079:*" />
      </bindings>
  </site>
  ```

Note the bindingInformation attribute value is:

```
*:{PortNumber}:*
```

instead of:

```
*:{PortNumber}:localhost
```

Comment: What if the website I'm working on doesn't seem to appear there?

Comment: Not had that issue before, so I'm not sure. What version of VS are you using - if it's VS2015, I think things have changed and the config file is placed within the project now (though haven't looked at this in detail yet)

Comment: The location of the config files is not the issue. My issue is I don't seem to find my project in the `applicationhost.config` file.