# unrecognised guid format in visual studio 2013 with update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows

I am using visual studio 2013 it's working fine but after update 3 when i try to load any solution or .cs file its gives me unrecognized guid format error and not opening any of my files. Any help in this regard is highly appretiated

Comment: after searching a lot, the only solution to this problem is to create a new user account and use visual studio with this account. It will then work perfectly fine.

Comment: Try running as administrator:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122254/how-do-i-fix-unrecognized-guid-format/28106919#28106919

Answer (score 0):

The below answer solve my problem : 
- Navigate to devenv.exe by right clicking Visual Studio from start, click    properties, and select "Open File Location...". 
- Right click on devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot Compatibility". 
- Click "Troubleshoot Program" 
- Check "The program opens but doesn't display correctly"
- Click "Next"
- Click "Test the program"
- Confirm everything opens correctly
- Click "Next"
- Click "Yes, save these settings for this program"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33813249/3926461

Answer (score 0):

Deleting below registry key resolved issue for me

1. run regedit command
2. Browse to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
3. Delete the Visual Studio entry