# running VS 2013 Ultimate as administrator in windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, elevated-privileges

I'm attempting to run VS Ultimate 2013 in elevated privileges so that I can use IIS8 to host and debug web projects. When I follow the steps in [Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8) I still get the same error and can not start VS. I've also tried checking the "Run As Administrator" checkbox in the compatibility tab of the actual VS executable...

The error I'm getting is the same as in this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/29/how-to-fix-the-application-cannot-start-error.aspx

Comment: What is the error when you try to use IIS8 when debugging web projects?

Comment: @NikolayKostov, I'm not getting an error with IIS8. The error I get is from VS itself. When I start up VS without administrator privileges and attempt to link the project to run in my local IIS instance instead of IIS Express I get a warning indicating that I need to run VS with administrator privileges. When I try to "Run As Administrator" on VS I get the same error as in this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/29/how-to-fix-the-application-cannot-start-error.aspx.