# How to Fix Unrecognized Guid format in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting an "Unrecognized Guid format" error when I try to open my project in Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine (upgraded from Windows 7).

This did not always occur for me. I originally made VS studio open as administrator (because my project needed it at the time) by following the steps in the anwser here: [Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)
I then decided I wanted to switch back to not having it open as admin. To try and switch back I again ran the compatibility troubleshooter, this time I selected "try recommended settings". After doing this I am now getting the Guid error every time I open my project and I can no longer run it. I even get it if I open VS as admin like I did before.

I even tried uninstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling it but that did not work either.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I am guessing you used to run Visual Studio as Administrator. This did it for me. The answer is to delete the compatibility entry in the registry.

1. Type Windows+R on the keyboard to open the Run dialog
2. Type regedit and press enter
3. Browse to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
4. Delete the Visual Studio entry

Comment: YUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUURSSS!!! THANK YOU MY GOOD FRIEND YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!!!

Comment: @user2481095 please mark this as the answer. This worked for me with vs2017 aswell.

Comment: Superstar! This just ended a 60-minute troubleshoot.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this on Windows 10 by using the Troubleshoot compatibility tool. It has to do with an extra checkbox being enabled.

- Navigate to devenv.exe by right clicking Visual Studio from start, click 
  properties, and select "Open File Location...".
- Right click on devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot Compatibility".
- Click "Troubleshoot Program"
- Uncheck "it worked with older versions of windows"
- Click "Next"
- Click "Test the program"
- Confirm everything opens correctly
- Click "Next"
- Click "Yes, save these settings for this program"

Comment: Worked for me with VS 2017. Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me says "Do you want to try again" after the first "Next"