# Undo Visual Studio always running with elevated privileges

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, elevated-privileges

Visual Studio always runs with elevated privileges for me, and I want to prevent that. I don't remember how or when I might have set this.

What I do know is that I tried the advice in following links and **it didn't fix** the issue for me - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41602199/492336) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1278821/how-do-i-undo-uac-admin-permission-elevation-for-visual-studio-2017).

I'm running it directly from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` to make sure it's not an issue with a shortcut and it still has Elevated Privileges.

I deleted the VS entry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`, I checked in `HKLM` as well. I reran the "Troubleshoot` wizard unchecking everything. None of it works - it always shows with "Elevated" as "Yes" in Task Manager

[image]

Renaming it to something else like `devenv_.exe` makes it run with "Elevated" as "No", but then it refuses to start and just shows an error message.

So how do I convince Windows 10 that I truly do not want it to run with Elevated Privileges?

Comment: This is normally configured in the shortcut you click to start VS.  Click Advanced and untick the "Run as Administrator" checkbox.

Comment: Even when I start it from the file itself at `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" `  and it still has Elevated Privileges. I don't use a shortcut.

Comment: Is there a way to trace privilege elevation reasons - i.e. what causes Windows to decide to elevate privileges? Are there logs or something like that, maybe in Process Monitor?