# I can not build the generated UWP project by Zebble

Tags: xamarin.android, uwp, xamarin.uwp, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I created a sample project using Zebble Extension for Visual Studio.
The related projects created successfully but unfortunately when I tried to compile the UWP project, the build process failed with the following error:

```
Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 10, Column 13, Reason: '$solutionname$' violates pattern constraint of '[-.A-Za-z0-9]+'. The attribute 'Name' with value '$solutionname$' failed to parse.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means the Zebble extension was unable to run the Zebble CLI tool (Zebble.exe) upon creation of your new project in Visual Studio.

Normally this is because of security restrictions. So solve that, you should:

- **Run Visual Studio as administrator before creating a new project.**

*NOTE:*

Alternatively, you can configure your Visual Studio process (devenv.exe) to always run as administrator. This can be handy to prevent other problems in the future (such as debugging a process) using:

[Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

*(works in Windows 10 too)*

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. The problem is solved.