# Why is the Windows 'For developers' Settings dialog window appearing each time I create a new Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution project?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-zebble, zebble

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I am trying to follow the video instructions for creating a new project found here: http://zebble.net/docs/creating-a-new-project

I do the following:

1. I ensure the Zebble extension is installed
2. I click the start screen's 'New Project' link
3. I select 'Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution' as project type
4. I name the project 'My application'
5. I click the 'OK' button

What happens next is:

- The Windows 'Settings' dialog window appears on top off my Visual Studio window and in the left hand pane 'For developers' is selected (the same dialog that would appear if you pressed the Windows key on your keyboard and then typed "settings" followed by pressing the Enter key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the Windows 'For developers' Settings dialog window appearing each time, you need to enable your device for development.

To enable Developer mode:

1. From the For developers settings dialog, choose the 'Developer mode'
2. Read the disclaimer for the setting you chose, then click Yes to accept the change.

After clicking Yes, you may be prompted to restart your computer.

Source: [Enable your device for development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Zebble Visual
   Studio extension.
2. Try running your visual studio in admin mode.

Also see [I can not build the generated UWP project by Zebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232322/i-can-not-build-the-generated-uwp-project-by-zebble/43232633#43232633)