# Unable to access the IIS metabase

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, iis

An ASP.NET web project loads with up the solution, but I get this error

> The Web Application Project is configured to use IIS. Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

How can this be solved?

Comment: have you tried this `aspnet_regiis -i` in command prompt for visual studio

Comment: Nope. Not sure where or how to do that. Did not know VS had command promp.

Comment: try as per below in ur command prompt `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga` ASPNET

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

Comment: See answer here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase

Answer (score 33):

This may have nothing to do with registering ASP/IIS. The reason is exactly what the error message says: Visual Studio devenv.exe is not running with sufficient privileges to access the IIS process, and it needs to do this if your solution contains a web project whose Web settings say to use IIS rather than the VS dev server.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Run VS as an Administrator and reopen the solution/project.
2. Edit the web application's project file with a text editor and change this line
   from True to False:

   ```
    <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
   ```

That will stop it using IIS and demanding higher privileges.

The reason VS demands Admin privileges is, I believe, because it will try and create the IIS web site for you on demand if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This worked for me, even with an Express version. Quick note: it only took modifying the project file in Notepad. Administrative privileges was not required in my case.

Answer (score 11):

An answer that worked for me can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460774/3005965

Basically, go to %systemroot%/inetsrv/config. When prompt appears saying you need admin privileges, click Continue.

This should clear up your issue.

Comment: This sorted it for me, but the path is %SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? I was either using Windows 7 or 8 (sorry, I don't remember which, I've been through several machines since I made this post).

Comment: Windows 10, but I doubt it's been moved.

Answer (score 7):

Just try to access Visual studio as Admin right click and choose run as administrator.
may fixes this problem.
and take a look at this [link](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2012/10/04/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase.aspx) for instructions on creating a shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when I had copied a project to a new project. I opened the project file (.csproj) and removed the value from the IISUrl element:

from: `<IISUrl>http://localhost:21222</IISUrl>`

to: `<IISUrl></IISUrl>`

Comment: This helped me - but it means your not using IIS but instead the build-in development web-server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered the .NET framework with IIS? You need to run the `aspnet_regiis.exe` utility found at `%WindowsDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.y.zzzz\.`  Run it as administrator as follows:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

`-i` : Installs the version of ASP.NET that is associated with `Aspnet_regiis.exe` and updates the script maps at the IIS metabase root and below. Only the script maps for applications that use an earlier version of ASP.NET are updated. Applications that use a later version are not affected.

Find out more about the utitlity [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs if you modified your Machine.config and added some "invalid lines":
For example, I added some appSettings, to the configuration section (which IIS didn't like).

Answer (score 0):

Just register your Web-project in your local IIS. All the settings you will find in *.csproj file. That works for me.

Comment: To make this a complete answer, please include an explanation of *how* to do that.

Answer (score 0):

first uncheck internet information service from turn windows features on or off.
then uninstall iis from your system and restart it. after restarting it install iis again from `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34679` and try to open again.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Close Visual Studio

Step 2: Go to Project Folder and find ".vs" folder Note: It may be hidden

Step 3: Delete ".vs" folder

Step 4: Open Project Again