# Error: Unable to access IIS metabase

Tags: windows, web-services, wcf, iis

I am trying to create a web service on WCF. But whenever I try to create a new Web Service Application Project, it gives the following error

**ERROR**

```
"Unable to access IIS Metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS websites on your machine"
```

I followed these two posts for help, but it didnt work

[Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

[Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598321/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

Also, I have all the IIS components installed on my system and I am running VS2013 as administrator. I'll be very thankful if anybody provide me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote [a post about that](http://www.ryadel.com/en/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase-error-and-how-to-fix-it/) on my blog, handling the two most causes generating that error. The one that worked for me was the first one, i.e. permanently granting the current user access to the IIS Metabase folders:

Press ALT+E, navigate to the following folder(s):

**Windows 7 and Windows 8.1**

```
%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config
```

**Windows 8 Professional**

```
%systemroot%\inetsrv\config
```

Hit Enter, grant access to the given folder and also to the `\Export\` folder inside it and you should be ok.