# migration visual studio WebFroms project 2010 to 2015 load failed (Unable to access the IIS metabase)

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows Server 2012R2 version with IIS installed.
I'm trying to migrate my solution from Visual Studio 2010 to VS 2015 SP3 Entreprise. 
The problem that my WebForms project get load failed error. When I try to right-click and reload the project, I get the following error message:

> Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:57011/ failed with
>   the error: Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have
>   sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine..

(Cannot put image)

Of course I have already searched for a solution and found the following pages, but it does not help:

[Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

http://automagicallyprogramming.com/post/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase-you-do-not-have-sufficient-privilege-to-access-iis-web-sites-on-your-machine

(and others)

They say to check :

1. Running Visual Studio as Administrator
2. Running aspnet_regiis.exe -ga MyUserName
3. Running aspnet_regiis.exe -I
4. Checked security here: %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config

I have already tried 1 and 4, for 2 and 3 I don't understand what to do .
I have execute it as following

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -ga
>   net1\mbasp
>
> Start granting net1\mbasp access to the IIS metabase and other
>   directories used by ASP.NET.
>
> Finished granting net1\mbasp access to the IIS metabase and other
>   directories used by ASP.NET.
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
>
> Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).

I don't think that the error "Unable to access the IIS metabase" is about IIS, but maybe about IIS Express. 
Do you know where there is a configuration of IIS Express in VS2015 or do you have another idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access the IIS metabase ASP.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459396/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase-asp-net)

Comment: no, it dosn't help. I already uninstall and reinstall VS, IIS and IIS Express. I think that there are some config files strored somewhere which make it fail.

Comment: I even cannot start a new Web application, I obtain the same error. Moreover, It already worked the first time when I installed the community version. But I have remove it, because of other problems with installation: some components was missing (due to the proxy settings)