# Fresh Install Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I am getting an error message that reads as follows when I try to create a new emty web project:

"Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:

Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine."

I am an Administrator account, and run VS2013 as administrator I tried the fix found at this link

[Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

I didn't understand the answer and don't have enough rep to comment and ask. When Altron suggests how to fix it, I clicked through the folders, and said continue, but I don't understand what he meant by "Changing the shortcut back to "Run as me"". This might not be my issue, but if it is can someone please clarify for me what he means or how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with Run as administrator when you open your Visual Studio[image]

[image]

Comment: I do that already. It happens when I try to create the project/application. Not when I open Visual Studio.

Comment: thats interesting i just updated my answer with one more image so can you see the (Administrator) at the top of your Visual Studio project/application

Comment: Yeah I have that at the top of mine as well. I don;t know where I can attach another image but it is there.

Comment: Np I got that. did you try this as in link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5cb9c7-af77-4bcd-8421-e813aff88bd3/help-with-visual-studio-2012-error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase?forum=visualstudiogeneral     "I think we encountered a similar problem at work. For us, the solution was to go into Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off... inside that, we had to select Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatibility -> IIS Metabse and IIS 6 configuration compatibility."

Comment: I'm still getting the error. I gave that a shot. I'm gonna try a reboot, but that so far has not worked. I'm still running as Administrator.

Comment: I still don't have anything. I still get the error when I try to create a web forms application. Any more ideas on what my issue could be? :/