# Creation of virtual directory failed Unable to access IIS metabase - tried about 100 answers

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm not fortunate to give modern Operating System "currently" and so my current situation is

1. Window 7 Enterprise   I do have admin access
2. Visual Studio 2013 , 2015
3. IIS 7.5  / IIS Express 10

I have tried **uninstalling IIS and IIS express** but I end up with issues around permissions with the **IIS metabase**.   I have tried many solutions and hacks and this is the longest I have ever spent on something with IIS and permissions.

I do have a feeling that a lot of this is related to the domain that I'm on, along with %USERProfile%   and settings that are to network drives that I do not even have access to.

[image]

Comment: I think it is fixed with a registry path change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iis      136,181 results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 2012.

It was a file access issue to %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config

Take a look at this post by GordonK2004 (highest rated one)

[Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I tried that...  I ended up fixing with changing various registry paths that pointed towards bad network paths.   thx

Comment: Worked for me when VS 2015 failed to load a project.