# Visual Studio Web Project does not shown on VS2015

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

I hava cloned a web Project from git but Project content is not shown on Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

I have tried to reload the Project. But, it is not working too. You can find error message for reload here.

```
C:\Path\Project.Web.csproj : error  : The Web Application Project Wise.Monitor.Web is configured to use IIS.  Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.
```

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It is not related to git. It was a permission problem.

Just go to following folder, and allow Access when a pop up shown asking for permission. Thats all.

```
c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config
```

You can find more details on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase).