# Unable to access the IIS metabase w VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I'm receiving the following error when I try to run my ASP.Net Core 1.1 app w/ IIS Express:

> The following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express for project MyCompany.IdentityApp. Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

---

I've reviewed the [existing SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase) and none of the fixes address the issue.  I'm thinking things have changed since then.

1. If I open VS as admin, I get this error
2. If I open VS **w/o** admin rights, I **don't** get this error
3. I can open different ASP.Net Core 1.1 web app and it runs fine from VS 2017 w/ IIS express
4. I checked my `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv` dir and there is no `Config` folder there to grant my account rights to

VS 2017 Version: 15.4.4

---

[MSFT Developer Community Issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157851/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config`

Credit to Bill Hiebert for the fix!

[Visual Studio Developer Community Reference thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157851/unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase.html)