# Creation of the virtual directory failed in Visual Studio 2017 with error "Unable to access the IIS metabase"

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I am not able to create a new ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio 2017 due to the following error. Only the solution file is getting created and the project file is not attaching to the solution file.

[image]

If I try to Add the project file to the solution, then I am getting the following error,

[image]

I have admin rights in my development PC and tried running VS as administrator.

I tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) and nothing worked for me.

Even I tried repairing the Visual Studio 2017 and no luck.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have admin rights" is useless. You need to run Visual Studio as administrator (UAC prompt), and Visual Studio window title should have (Administrator) in it.

Comment: @LexLi, I tried that option also. I've updated my question.