# Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, csproj, metabase

I am unable to load a csproj in VS2015. I get the `Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:<Port_Number>/ failed with the error: Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.` error. I tried the following:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled IIS
- Gave access to `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config` & `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\Export` folders
- Changed `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` to `<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>`
- Rebooted the system

None of the above worked. Could you advise how to fix this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in two ways：

1. Launch Visual Studio with Administrator priviledges.
2. Permanently grant the IIS Metabase folder permissions to the current user.

   You can press Win + E to open a Windows Explorer instance, then write the following line on the topmost address bar depending on the OS you’re using, As soon as you hit the Enter key the following popup will appear, asking you if you want to permanently grant access to that folder to the current user, click on the Continue button, then try to open up the \Export\ subfolder with a couple mouse clicks and repeat the same process. You’re done: from now on, you’ll be able to launch Visual Studio with default priviledges and your IIS instance will work without hassles.

   More information about setting you can refer to this link: [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460774/13336642)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to load a visual studio 2015 solution. The solution would load but website project would remain unloaded and the output window would show that error message.

- Click the unloaded website project in the solution explorer
- Go to the properties section dock-window, there is a property called "File Path"
- If it is set to an URL, change it to the full physical path to the website.
- Reload the project.