# how do I publish a WCF service to IIS?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

At this point I have a WCF Service working using Cassini/IIS Express with a .NET client when I run it from Visual Studio, but am having difficulties when I try to publish it to directly IIS.  For some reason I cannot connect to the WCF Service.  I have been researching how to publish by looking at these Microsoft online docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-service-publishing

For now I am just trying to publish it locally, where I choose to publish it to the `File System` to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GeoService` but when I try to browse to the server I only get errors like:

BTW, I have tried browsing to these sites:

http://localhost/GeoService.svc

http://localhost/GeoService/

http://localhost/GeoService/GeoService.svc

Where I get errors like:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

Please note that the full source code is here:

https://github.com/john1726/WcfEndToEnd.git

What am I missing?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Comment: WCF is not enabled by default on Windows, so you need some extra steps (for Windows Server releases you can refer to https://help.genesys.com/pureconnect/mergedprojects/wh_tr/mergedprojects/wh_tr_web_portal_marquee/desktop/activate_windows_communication_foundation_wcf.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I tried to perform the steps in the Microsoft online docs but I ended up having to update the server by going to `Programs and Features` -> Turn `Windows Features on or off` and selecting .NET Framework `4.8 Advanced Services` where I enabled all options because the `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` and `ServiceModelReg.exe -ia` commands are no longer supported:

- ASP.NET 4.8
- WCF Services

For WCF Services I turned on:

```
HTTP Activation
MSMQ Activation
Named Pipe Activation 
TCP Activation
TCP Port Sharing
```

Also I turned on `Windows Process Activation Service`:

```
.NET Environment
```

Furthermore, I had to turn on `Directory Browsing` by going to `IIS Manager` and navigating to `MyServer` -> `Sites` -> `My Site` and clicking on `Directory Browsing` and choosing `Enable`.

Another step I did was enable IIS 6 metabase by in the turning features on or off I went to `Internet Information Services` -> `Web Management Tools` -> `IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility`

See [Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase)

Thus the URL I ended up using was:

http://localhost/GeoService/GeoService.svc